# XSLT 1.0 Copy attribute value as text and drop the attribute

Tags: xslt

I want to copy the attiribute value and move it as text of element and drop the attribute for that element. Note: it has to match the element name as i dont want to drop the attribute for other elements.

Input:

```
<a name = "attr" value = "text"/>
```

Expected

```
<a name = "attr"> text </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose this is a sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <a name="attr" value="text" />
</root>
```

Then this stylesheet will result in the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[local-name() != 'value']"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
    <a name="attr">text</a>
</root>
```

The default template just copies recursively. The second template with match `<a>` elements. It first applies templates for the attributes that are not `value`, then copies the text of attribute `value`. It must be done like this because if attribute value appears before other attributes, the opening  tag would already be ended to start its text content, and by then other attributes can't be copied anymore.